# How to solve the Fick's partial differential equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, computational-physics, differential-equations, diffusion

Consider a finite diffusion in which the concentration profiles at different times are like
[image]

How to solve the differential equation as opposed to the common solution for semi-infinite/infinite condition boundary?

My question is the solution of the differential equation
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2}$$
with the initial boundary condition of
$$c(0,t)=A$$
different when the boundary condition is changed from
$$c(\infty,t)=0$$
to
$$c(x=l,t)=0$$

Comment: Hi Kama. As a general rule solving PDEs can be very hard and we often have to resort to numerical methods. Where analytical solutions are possible there is a huge array of techniques for attacking the problem.  You'll need to make it clearer exactly what you are asking for us to be able to help.

Comment: @JohnRennie I edited the question to clarify my question.

Answer (score 3):

The graph you have presented is the solution to the following problem:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$subject to the initial condition

$u=0$ at t = 0

and the boundary conditions

$u=1$ at x = 0

and

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ at x = L

The first step in solving this is to write $$u(x,t)=1-U(t,x)$$where U is the solution to the following set of equations:
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}$$subject to the initial condition

$U=1$ at t = 0

and the boundary conditions

$U=0$ at x = 0

and

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=0$ at x = L

The next step in obtaining a solution is expressing U(t,x) in the form of a product of a function of t and a function of x:

$$U(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$$
I'm not going to continue with the rest of the solution because you can find it in any book covering partial differential equations as well as in virtually all books on heat and mass transfer, such as Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Comment: Sorry for my naivety, but what is the purpose of defining $U(t,x)$ from $u(x,t)$? They seem similar partial differential equations, and the solutions should be similar. Why not separate the variable directly for $u(x,t)$?

Comment: Experience.  I don't remember whether I learned this on my own (the hard way) or whether I was taught it.  But, if the final steady state is not zero, the separation will not work.  This is because the separated solution is characterized by exponential decay, so that part of it must decay to zero.  So what must remain must be the steady state solution (a function only of x).  So the first thing to do is to represent the solution as the sum of the steady state solution plus a transient part.